# discretize the integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

The question is: Show that 
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{1}\int_{2^{k}r}^{2^{k+1}r}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{r}f(t)dt.
$$

But i find that $
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{1}\int_{2^{k}r}^{2^{k+1}r}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{4r}f(t)dt
$. Where is my mistake or is the question wrong?

Comment: I think the question is wrong.

Comment: @B.Goddard do you think my answer is true?

Comment: Yes, unless there's some convergence problem.